# Creating a dictionary of lists from a file

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list in the following format in a txt file :

```
Shoes, Nike, Addias, Puma,...other brand names 
Pants, Dockers, Levis,...other brand names
Watches, Timex, Tiesto,...other brand names
```

how to put these into dictionary like this format:
     dictionary={Shoes: [Nike, Addias, Puma,.....] 
                 Pants: [Dockers, Levis.....]
                 Watches:[Timex, Tiesto,.....]
                 }

How to do this in a for loop rather than manual input.

i have tried

```
       clothes=open('clothes.txt').readlines() 
       clothing=[]
       stuff=[] 
       for line in clothes:
               items=line.replace("\n","").split(',')
               clothing.append(items[0])
               stuff.append(items[1:])



   Clothing:{}
         for d in clothing:
            Clothing[d]= [f for f in stuff]
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a more concise way to do things, though you'll probably want to split it up a bit for readability

```
wordlines = [line.split(', ') for line in open('clothes.txt').read().split('\n')]
d = {w[0]:w[1:] for w in wordlines}
```

Comment: 1) a genexpr would be a bit nicer, 2) iterate over the file instead of splitting (then just `line.rstrip()`). Otherwise, nice answer.

Comment: You mean something like `(line.rstrip().split(', ') for line in open('clothes.txt').readlines())`?

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
file = open('clothes.txt')
clothing = {}
for line in file:
    items = [item.strip() for item in line.split(",")]
    clothing[items[0]] = items[1:]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it will remove the need for replacing line breaks and is quite simple, but effective:

```
clothes = {}
with open('clothes.txt', 'r', newline = '/r/n') as clothesfile:
    for line in clothesfile:
        key = line.split(',')[0]
        value = line.split(',')[1:]
        clothes[key] = value
```

The 'with' statement will make sure the file reader is closed after your code to implement the dictionary is executed. From there you can use the dictionary to your heart's content!

Comment: Certainly true; it could easily have been stored into a local variable to remove the redundancy, but for the sake of clarity in this example it is done twice.

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension you could do:

```
clothes=[line.strip() for line in open('clothes.txt').readlines()]
clothingDict = {}
for line in clothes:
  arr = line.split(",")
  clothingDict[arr[0]] = [arr[i] for i in range(1,len(arr))]
```